# Sync certain value from mysql to sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite

I am developing an android app which uses both sqlite and mysql. I have some item stored in sqlite with some entity using the same value as the one stored in mysql.

Example, sqlite has 3 rows which are id, name and price and mysql has more than 3 rows but the value of name and price is the same for both. Is there anyway to sync the name and price so that the value in sqlite will always be the same as the one in mysql?

Answer (score 0):

Both are a Relational Database. Try using the JOIN technique. I would prefer OUTER JOIN (or FULL OUTER JOIN).

EG:

```
SELECT id, name, price
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id

UNION

SELECT id, name, price
FROM `user`
RIGHT JOIN `course` on user.course = course.id;
```

[Please read this](http://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-sql-joins-mysql-database/)